# How can I efficiently best fit large data with large numbers of variables

Tags: math, statistics

I have a data set with, 10 million rows and 1,000 variables, and I want to best fit those variables, so I can estimate a new rows value. I am using Jama's QR decomposition to do it (better suggestions welcome, but I think this question applies to any implementation). Unfortunately that takes too long.

It appears I have two choices.  Either I can split the data into, say, 1000 size 10,000 chunks and then average the results. Or I can add up every , say, 100 rows, and stick those combined rows into the QR decomposition.

One or both ways may be mathematical disasters, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: This may be better suited to [Stats.SE] or [Math.SE].

Comment: You're right, I'll close and open in math.

Answer (score 0):

For such big datasets I'd have to say you need to use HDF5. HDF5 is Hierarchical Data Format v5. They have C/C++ implementation APIs, and other bindings for different languages. HDF uses B-trees to keep index of datasets.

HDF5 is supported by Java, MATLAB, Scilab, Octave, Mathematica, IDL, Python, R, and Julia.

Unfortunately I don't know more than this about it. However I'd suggest you'd begin your research with a simple exploratory internet search!